# Symfony 2 redirecting out of private function

Tags: php, symfony

In my Application I'm using a init function to init an action
the init function validate the user input 
(for example the user is looking for an product what not exist -> the init function should redirect him to an errorpage "product ... not found")

```
 /**
 * @Route("/route/{var}", name="xyzbundle_xyz_index")
 * @Template("VendorXyzBundle:xyz:index.html.twig")
 */
public function indexAction ($var) 
{
    $xyz = $this->initxyz($var);
    ...
    .. more code
    .              
}
```

And there is a private function in this controller that should validate the from url given parameter and if it is wrong (dont exist in database etc), the private function should redirect

```
private function init($var)
{
    if($this->databasesearchforexyz($var)){
        // redirect to Errorpage (No xyz found named ...)
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('xyz_error_...'));
    }
    if($this->checksomethingelse($var)){
        // redirect to some other error page
    }
}
```

Please note, these are not my real method/variable/path/etc. names.

The problem is, it is not redirecting.

Comment: this doesn't works, it's not redirecting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check if the init function returns an actual response, then you can return it directly from the main code. Like this:

```
public function indexAction ($var) 
{
    $xyz = $this->initxyz($var);
    if ($xyz instanceof \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response) {
        return $xyz;
    }
    ...
    .. more code
    .              
}
```

Btw, if you only need to check database existance you can use symfony's [paramconverter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html)

Comment: I also thought about this - but it indroduces one more if statement which is not good. If there was no private method, there would be no need for if statement - just return instantly. So need better solution.
Using exceptions sound like wrong also - because exceptions are when there are errors. But if there is success, does not sound good.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some suggestion.

Return `true` from the init function if there's no redirect and return `false` if there's a redirect.

Example:

```
private function init($var) {
    if ($error) {
        // An error occurred, redirect
        $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('xyz_error_...'));
        return false;
    }
    // Else, everything alright
    return true;
}

public function indexAction ($var) {
    if (!$this->init($var)) {
        // Failed to init, redirection happening
        return;
    }
    // Continue as normal
}
```

Comment: this would work, but in my opinion the solution from alex88 is for my application more usable, thanks for your efforts

Answer (score 0):

Using the answer of @alex88, I aggregate an exception and an exception listener to do the redirect. That avoid me to repeat the condition over and over again, because my function could redirect the user under different scenarios.

**1. Controller**

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use AppBundle\Exception\UserHasToBeRedirectedException;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{

    public function indexAction(...)
    {
        ...
        $this->userHasToBeRedirected();
        ...
    }

    private function userHasToBeRedirected()
    {
        ...
        if ($userHasToBeRedirected) {
            $response = $this->redirect($this->generateUrl(...));
            throw new UserHasToBeRedirectedException($response);
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

**2. Exception**

```
namespace AppBundle\Exception;

use Exception;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class UserHasToBeRedirectedException extends Exception
{
    private $response;

    public function __construct(Response $response)
    {
        $this->response = $response;
    }

    public function getResponse()
    {
        return $this->response;
    }

    public function setResponse(Response $response)
    {
        $this->response = $response;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

**3. Exception Listener**

```
namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForExceptionEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpExceptionInterface;

use AppBundle\Exception\UserHasToBeRedirectedException;

class ExceptionListener
{
    public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
    {
        $exception = $event->getException();

        ...

        if ($exception instanceof UserHasToBeRedirectedException) {
            $response = $exception->getResponse();
            $event->setResponse($response);
        }

        ...
    }
}
```

**4. Register the service at service.yml**

```
...
appBundle.exception_listener:
    class: AppBundle\EventListener\ExceptionListener
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception }
...
```

#### For more information:

[Symfony Documantation about Events](http://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html)